# Date format different on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

When I execute the code below, I am getting my dates formatted as `04-07-2015` which is as expected what I want.

But when I execute the same code on *another* server, I am getting date as `7/4/2015`. Why?

Here is my code on pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillProject();
    }
    grdData.Visible = false;
    TxtIndate.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    txtOutDate.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: it depends on system culture settings

Comment: @Grundy: Can I somehow ajdust that, coz I want to show a demo to the client

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting"? Do you mean both `ToShortDateString()` calls deliver different results on the same page? What kind of controls are `TxtIndate` and `txtOutDate`?

Comment: @CodeCaster: `TxtIndate` are input controls. and yes both delivers different dates

Comment: That's not what I was asking. Please explain your problem properly. Do you mean **1** both textboxes display the same format, but that the format differs per machine, or **2** do both textboxes display a different format on the same machine? If the latter, is one a TextBox and the other a MaskedTextBox or other control that does input formatting?

Comment: @CodeCaster: My issue is `Do you mean both textboxes display the same format, but that the format differs per machine?`

Comment: @nad so you mean: on different servers different dates?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, on my server date format was different

Comment: Then specify the correct culture on the format.

Comment: I m sorry for mistake, but I hope I mentioned the date was coming different on the server

Comment: @nad see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ToShortDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method uses [`ShortDatePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `CurrentCulture` settings.

*Probably* your servers have different culture settings, that's why when you run this code, you get different string representations of your `DateTime`.

If you wanna get same representation in both server, set the same culture on both server in region and language settings or use [custom date and time format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
TxtIndate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

or as a better way as [Matt mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220960/date-format-different-on-server/31220984?noredirect=1#comment50449401_31220984), use `InvariantCulture` with string format like;

```
TxtIndate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Comment: It would still be good to specify the `Invariant` culture, just in case one of the cultures uses a non-gregorian calendar.  For example, you might get `"17-09-1436"` if the culture is `"ar-SA"`, since it uses the `UmAlQuaraCalendar`.

Comment: @nad If your `CurrentCulture` doesn't use `GregorianCalendar` by default calendar, yes, otherwise, you don't need it.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I have used in aspx as `<input id="txtOutDate" runat="server" maxlength="20" type="text" style="text-align: right;
                        width: 75px" readonly="readonly" />
                    <cc3:Calendar ID="CalOutdate" runat="server" CultureName="en-GB" DatePickerImagePath="Images/icon2.gif"
                        DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="txtOutDate">
                    </cc3:Calendar>`

Answer (score 1):

From the c# code it seems impossible that the same code produces two different time formats. So as far as I can tell, we have to find it somewhere else.

*Maybe* the source of the confusion is in two different types of `input` controls in your HTML output. One `type=text`, one `type=date` that could explain the different formatting since the HTML 5 date control renders differently. So one date is the server formatted value, the other is the browser, and possibly client culture, formatted value.

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have said, this is due to the different cultures.

If having the same date format is important (caveat, users expect to see dates in the format they're used to for their culture) then you can always set it explicitly.

```
var myCultureDateFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

// Short date string
var shortDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(myCultureDateFormat.ShortDatePattern);

// Long date string
var longDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(myCultureDateFormat.LongDatePattern);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks James for your explanation.